# Why is regex [0-9]{0,2} not greedy in sed?

Tags: shell-script, sed, regular-expression

```
echo '123980925sriten34=ienat' | sed -e 's/^.*\?\([1-9][0-9]\{0,2\}\+\)\([%=+-]\).*/ \1 \2 /'
```

is giving the result:

```
 4 =
```

I am expecting:

```
 34 =
```

What am I not understanding?

(Oh and I even added the `+` and `?` to make doubly sure, but afaik `{0,2}` should be greedy without them.)

Comment: perl -pe 's/^.*?([1-9][0-9]{0,2})([%=+-]).*/ $1 $2 /' is less annoying

Comment: Isn't it more to do with the fact that the preceding `.*` **is** greedy?

Comment: ... perhaps you're thinking that the following `\?` makes it non-greedy?

Comment: wrt `i even added the + and ? to make doubly sure` - that will probably make doubly sure the regexp won't work. You can't just throw random characters into a regexp and hope they'll somehow improve it. Also `\?` and `\+` are GNU sed only so if you aren't running GNU sed then they're going to be treated as literal chars - the POSIX equivalents are `\{0,1\}` and `\{1,\}` respectively.

Comment: `\+` and `\?` aren't BRE, but even if they were, stacking the repetition specifiers (`*` and `?` or `{n,m}` and `+`) isn't defined.

Answer (score 11):

The problem, [as steeldriver states](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/531098/80216#comment982949_531098),
isn’t that the `[0-9]{0,2}` is non-greedy;
the problem is that the `.*?` before it is greedy. 
`sed` supports BRE and ERE, neither of which supports non-greedy matching. 
That’s a feature of PCREs. 
For example, the following commands:

```
$ echo 'aQbQc' | sed    's/.*\?Q/X/'
$ echo 'aQbQc' | sed    's/.*Q/X/'
$ echo 'aQbQc' | sed -r 's/.*?Q/X/'
$ echo 'aQbQc' | sed -r 's/.*Q/X/'
```

all output

```
Xc
```

(I’m not sure why it just ignores the `?`.)

See [Non-greedy match with SED regex (emulate perl's `.*?`)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/297686/80216).

Your description of the function that you want to perform is skimpy,
but I believe that I’ve reverse engineered it. 
You can get the desired effect by *not matching* the characters
before the number you want to match until after you’ve found the number:

```
$ echo '123980925sriten34=ienat' | sed -e 's/\([1-9][0-9]\{0,2\}\+\)\([%=+-]\).*/! \1 \2 /' -e 's/.*!//'
 34 =
```

replacing the `!` with any string known not to appear in the input data. 
If you have no such string, but you’re using GNU sed, you can use newline:

```
$ echo '123980925sriten34=ienat' | sed -e 's/\([1-9][0-9]\{0,2\}\+\)\([%=+-]\).*/\n \1 \2 /' -e 's/.*\n//'
 34 =
```

which, of course, cannot appear ***in*** any line.

Comment: wrt `I’m not sure why it just ignores the ?` - because `?` after another repetition RE metachar (`*` in this case) is undefined behavior per POSIX and since in other contexts it means `zero-or-1` just ignoring it is as reasonable approach as any. Essentially `.*?` should be treated as bug in a regexp as it doesn't have any sensible meaning (zero-or one repetitions of zero-or-more repetitions of any character - huh?).

Comment: On a GNU system, the repetition operators stack, `?` after `+` (using ERE syntax) makes the whole thing optional (same as `*`), and `{2,4}?` matches 0, 2, 3 or 4 repetitions (try `grep -Eoe 'ba{2,4}?b'` against `bb`, `bab`, `baab`). `*?` is just the same as `*` since `*` can already match zero repetitions. The thing where `?` makes a pattern non-greedy is a feature of Perl regexes.