# Converting html anchors to markdown using sed regex

Tags: sed, regular-expression, html, markdown

I've been slowly converting a blog of mine to markdown. The final thing to do is replacing all the html anchors with markdown.

I've come up this sed regex, which for all intents and purposes should do what I want, but it doesn't.

Source data:

```
$ cat /tmp/test
on <a href="https://www.reddit.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">reddit</a> or <a href="https://lifehacker.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Lifehacker</a>
```

Sed command:

```
$ sed -r 's/<a.*?href="(.*?)".*?>(.*?)<\/a>/[\2](\1)/g' /tmp/test
on [Lifehacker](https://lifehacker.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener)
```

What I want it to return:

```
on [Reddit](https://reddit.com/) or [Lifehacker](https://lifehacker.com/")
```

Comment: Is there a line break in `/tmp/test` or is that wrapping?

Comment: Sorry, that pasted bad. It's on one line. Fixed it

Comment: I dont think gnu sed supports non-greedy patterns. You can replace the 2nd `.*?` with `[^"]*`.

Comment: Using regular expressions to parse html is generally not a great idea (see the often quoted [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/10488700) on the topic). You may save yourself headaches by using a specialized html parser. Here, even [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) may be a convenient solution - e.g. `pandoc -f html -t markdown /tmp/test`.

Comment: @meuh while that fixes part of the issue, it still doesn't return both - only the last one is matched.

Comment: @fra-san while true, most of the syntax has been converted to markdown when I exported it from the old platform (WP), and using pandoc screws up the parts that are already converted.

Comment: @devilkin Based on my experience, I wouldn't recommend pandoc in general. But it happens to conveniently work in simple cases. You may just pipe single lines to it. Using regular expression to parse whole html documents is likely to screw things up too. Finally, you can have non-greedy matching in `sed`, but it requires [some work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/297686/315749).

Comment: @meuh thx for that comment on the fact that sed doesn't do non-greedy. Interesting tidbit I didn't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` uses basic and extended regular expressions (BRE/ERE). `.*?` is part of a Perl Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE).

To use PCRE, use `perl`:

```
$ perl -pe 's/<a.*?href="(.*?)".*?>(.*?)<\/a>/[\2](\1)/g' test
on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/) or [Lifehacker](https://lifehacker.com/)
```

- This is exactly the same expression as the original, but used with `perl -p` which reads & prints file line by line – like `sed` does

---

Here is a similar regex using ERE with `sed`:

```
$ sed -E 's/<a[^>]*href="([^"]*)[^>]*>([^<]*)[^>]*>/[\2](\1)/g' test
on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/) or [Lifehacker](https://lifehacker.com/)
```

- PCRE uses [a `?` following a quantifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) to match the shortest repetition, standard regular expressions do not
- Negated character classes are used to work around this

Comment: Thanks :) I was thinking of having a look at perl, but I was breaking my head why sed didn't work. Now I know... TIL :)