# Using sed to remove string between < >

Tags: sed

I want to remove the string between the first pair of < >

Original text:

```
< a href="ACM-Reference-Format.dbx"> ACM-Reference-Format.dbx < /a >
```

I want to be left with just

```
ACM-Reference-Format.dbx</a>
```

I tried using

```
sed 's/[<->]*/ but it only removed the first <
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-greedy match with SED regex (emulate perl's .\*?)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297686/non-greedy-match-with-sed-regex-emulate-perls)

Comment: See the answer by gresolio

Answer (score 1):

In regex `[]` will define a character class, which will match any character in between the brackets.
For example you could match any character in the alphabet between a-z with `[a-z]`. This won't help with your example.

What you want to do instead is match `<` followed by any character followed by `>`.

Usually you could to that with `<.*?>`, but as Panki pointed out `sed` doesn't support non-greedy matches.

You can instead match any character, except for `>` and `/`:

```
sed 's/<[^>\/]*>\s//'
```

**Example:**

```
─$ echo "< a href="ACM-Reference-Format.dbx"> ACM-Reference-Format.dbx < /a > " | sed 's/<[^>\/]*>\s//'
ACM-Reference-Format.dbx < /a >
```

**Explanation:**

```
<[^>\/]*>
<           #matches <
 [^   ]     #negated character class, matches any character except the ones specified
   > /      #the characters not to be matched
    \       #escaping the following slash to prevent it from being interpreted as special symbol
       *    #matches previous character between 0 and infinity times
        >   #matches >
```

Comment: Way better than my answer...

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Not necessarily better, as both lead to the same result, but easier than working with groups and reinserting them

Comment: you could use Eg: `@` as separator instead of `/` to avoid escaping.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```bsh
$ sed 's/[^>]*> \([^>]*\)/\1/' file # or string
ACM-Reference-Format.dbx < /a >
```

Comment: why not just : `'s/^[^>]*> //'` or `'s/^[^>]*>//'` to preserve the space?